# parsing json data from alpha vantage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, alpha-vantage

I am new to Ajax and JSON. I am facing issues with the parsing of Json data from the Alpha Vantage API. My project is to create a stock widget using the jive platform in a html5 widget and I have existing code using the yahoo finance api. The yahoo api url is no longer working and I found another api that is working and giving me json data. I have tried to work with the existing code but the trouble I am stumbling on is how to parse the code from json data to the html.

Also console is giving me the following error for the first line of the json data so I added a callback to the url thinking it would fix it
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// This version has been tested to work in Jive 4.0.15 and 5.0. It should work in Jive 4.5 but has not been tested
// Add the stock symbol here
  // var yourStockSymbol = 'LIFE';
</script>

<div id="stock_miniQuote_head" class="ajaxtrigger"><span id="stockSymbol"></span>&nbsp;(common stock)</div>

<div id="stock_miniQuote">
<div id="stockIndicator"><p>Retrieving stock information...</p></div>


    <div class="stock_divider">

      <div id="stock_left">
        <span class="stock_label">Price</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong">$<span id="stockAsk"></span></strong><br/>
      </div>


      <div id="stock_right">
        <span class="stock_label">Change</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockChange"></span></strong><br />
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockChangePercent"></span></strong><br />
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>


    </div>

      <div id="stock_body">

      <div id="stock_body_content">
        <span class="stock_label">Volume</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockVolume"></span></strong>
        <br /><br />
        <span class="stock_label">Average Daily Volume</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockAvgVolume"></span></strong>
        <br /><br />
        <span class="stock_label">52 Week Range</span><br/>
        <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockRange"></span></strong>

      </div>

      <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    </div>



</div>



<style>

#stockIndicator {
  text-align:left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: red;
}

.ajaxtrigger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

#stock_miniQuote_head {
  background-color:#464A55;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}

#stock_miniQuote {
  border-bottom-color:#DDDDDD;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px 5px;
  border-bottom-style:solid;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  border-left-color:#DDDDDD;
  border-left-style:solid;
  border-left-width:1px;
  border-right-color:#DDDDDD;
  border-right-style:solid;
  border-right-width:1px;
  border-top-color:initial;
  border-top-style:none;
  border-top-width:initial;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-top:10px;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 99%;
}

.stock_divider {
  border-bottom:1px solid #B2B0AD; padding-bottom:5px;
}

#stock_left {
  float:left; width:35%; height:50px; border-right:1px solid #B2B0AD; padding:0 15px;
}

#stock_right {
  float:right; width:*; padding:0 20px; vertical-align:text-top;
}

.stock_label {
  font-size:14px;
}

.stock_strong {
  font-size:17px;
}

#stock_body {
  padding:10px 0 15px;
}

#stock_body_content {
  float:left; width:170px; padding:0 15px;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

if ($('#jive-widgets-browser').css('display') == 'block') {
// Do Nothing as we are in edit mode

} else {
// Build the URL to Alpha Vantage
// var q = escape('select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("' + yourStockSymbol + '")');
var theURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=0787.HK&interval=1min&apikey=AOIAMG3WFZ8LS58W&callback=?";


$(document).ready(function(){
// Load function on launch
  $("#stockIndicator").show();
  doAjax(theURL);

// Function for refreshing the stock by clicking on the title header
$('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
  $("#stockIndicator").show();
  doAjax(theURL);
    return false;
  });

// Function to add commas to numbers for volume
  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

// Main function to make JSON request to Alpha Vantage for stock information
  function doAjax(url){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){
      var s = data.query.results;
          if(s){
      if(s.quote.Change > 0) {
        // Change the change text to green
        $('#stockChange').css({'color': 'green'});
        $('#stockChangePercent').css({'color': 'green'});
      } else {
        // Change the change text to red
        $('#stockChange').css({'color': 'red'});
        $('#stockChangePercent').css({'color': 'red'});
      }

      console.log('s is' + s);

      // This is where we add the JSON values back into the HTML above
      $('#stockSymbol').html(s.quote.symbol);
      $('#stockAsk').html(s.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
      $('#stockChange').html(s.quote.Change);
      $('#stockChangePercent').html(s.quote.ChangeinPercent);
      $('#stockVolume').html(numberWithCommas(s.quote.Volume));
      $('#stockAvgVolume').html(numberWithCommas(s.quote.AverageDailyVolume));
      $('#stockRange').html(s.quote.YearRange);

      $("#stockIndicator").hide();

          } else {
            var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
      $("#stockIndicator").show();
            $("#stockIndicator").html(errormsg);
          }
        }
      });

  }


  }); //end ready function

} //end first else





</script>
```

This is the json info

```js
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "0787.HK",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-12-07",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2017-12-07": {
            "1. open": "0.6700",
            "2. high": "0.6800",
            "3. low": "0.6600",
            "4. close": "0.6600",
            "5. volume": "20488001"
        }
        // More rows
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong and how do I do this correctly?

Comment: Did you mean to make the dataType 'jsonp' instead of 'json' which would match the response format?

Comment: I think the comma at the end of the third last bracket is causing problems.

Comment: @ChrisHappy that is the json output from the api, i shortened it to save space.

Comment: @Taplar I have revised it but it doesnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did you ever parse the JSON? I don't see `JSON.parse(...)` anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisHappy I have tried to grab the value from json here - starting here  $('#stockSymbol').html(s.quote.symbol); - i might be doing it wrong. how do i  target "1. open": "0.6700",

Comment: Okay, trying replaceing `var s = data.query.results;` with: `var s = JSON.parse(data.query.results;)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160751/discussion-between-user3730179-and-chris-happy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `&callback=?` from

```
var theURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=0787.HK&interval=1min&apikey=AOIAMG3WFZ8LS58W&callback=?";
```

and change `dataType :"jsonp"` to `dataType :"json"`.

```js
var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=0787.HK&interval=1min&apikey=AOIAMG3WFZ8LS58W';

jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your script was coded to retrieve data from yahoo finance.

I tried my best to rewrite part of the code in order to use ALPHAVANTAGE. I'd appreciate some feedback on it please.

```js
var theURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#stockIndicator").show();
  doAjax(theURL);

  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function() {
    $("#stockIndicator").show();
    doAjax(theURL);
    return false;
  });

  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

  function doAjax(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data) {

        var symbol = data['Meta Data']['2. Symbol']
        var lastRefreshed = data['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed']
        var lastTradePriceOnly = data['Time Series (1min)'][lastRefreshed]['4. close']
        var lastVolume = data['Time Series (1min)'][lastRefreshed]['5. volume']

        $('#stockSymbol').html(symbol);
        $('#stockAsk').html(lastTradePriceOnly);
        $('#stockVolume').html(numberWithCommas(lastVolume));
        $("#stockIndicator").hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#stockIndicator {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: red;
}

.ajaxtrigger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

#stock_miniQuote_head {
  background-color: #464A55;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#stock_miniQuote {
  border-bottom-color: #DDDDDD;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #DDDDDD;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #DDDDDD;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: initial;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-top-width: initial;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 99%;
}

.stock_divider {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B2B0AD;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#stock_left {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid #B2B0AD;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

#stock_right {
  float: right;
  width: *;
  padding: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.stock_label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.stock_strong {
  font-size: 17px;
}

#stock_body {
  padding: 10px 0 15px;
}

#stock_body_content {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stock_miniQuote_head" class="ajaxtrigger"><span id="stockSymbol"></span>&nbsp;(common stock)</div>

<div id="stock_miniQuote">
  <div id="stockIndicator">
    <p>Retrieving stock information...</p>
  </div>


  <div class="stock_divider">

    <div id="stock_left">
      <span class="stock_label">Price</span><br/>
      <strong class="stock_strong">$<span id="stockAsk"></span></strong><br/>
    </div>


    <div id="stock_right">
      <span class="stock_label">Change</span><br/>
      <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockChange"></span></strong><br />
      <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockChangePercent"></span></strong><br />
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>


  </div>

  <div id="stock_body">

    <div id="stock_body_content">
      <span class="stock_label">Volume</span><br/>
      <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockVolume"></span></strong>
      <br /><br />
      <span class="stock_label">Average Daily Volume</span><br/>
      <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockAvgVolume"></span></strong>
      <br /><br />
      <span class="stock_label">52 Week Range</span><br/>
      <strong class="stock_strong"><span id="stockRange"></span></strong>

    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

  </div>



</div>
```